# Java JFileChooser with Filter to supposedly display ONLY directories fail to show just directories

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filefilter

(Thanks in advance!  Please let me know if you need more info.  Sample code at the bottom.)

**Problem I'm trying to solve:**

I'm trying to get this JFileChooser object to display only directories (and not files), through the use of a javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter object that has this in the accept(File file) overridden method: `return file.isDirectory();`.  However, at least on my mac, it doesn't seem to prevent files from being displayed along with the directories (it does prevent files from being selected without using the setFileSelectionMode() method).

**Question**

Am I missing something?  If not, has anyone ever encountered this before?

**My understanding/assumptions:**

1. The magic should happen when you pass in a javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter object into the JFileChooser's `setFileFilter()` method.
2. Seems like my JFileChooser with setFileFilter() is behaving like its using of `setSelectionMode( JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY );`

**Code**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

// inside a method that's adding this to a JPanel

_fileChooser = new JFileChooser( "." );
_fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown( false );
_fileChooser.setFileFilter( new FolderFilter() );
// _fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY );
_panelMidLeft.add( _fileChooser );

// an inner class, defined somewhere else in the class

private class FolderFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {
  @Override
  public boolean accept( File file ) {
    return file.isDirectory();
  }

  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
    return "We only take directories";
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Alex

Comment: Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Other than the use of '_' (which in my case were to actually indicate instance variables), would you mind so kindly to point out a couple things, while I'm going through the docs on the web right now about the conventions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code works for me. My [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class ShowDirectoriesOnly {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser( "." );
      fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown( false );
      fileChooser.setFileFilter( new FolderFilter() );
      fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
      fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
   }

   private static class FolderFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {
      @Override
      public boolean accept( File file ) {
        return file.isDirectory();
      }

      @Override
      public String getDescription() {
        return "We only take directories";
      }
    }
}
```

If you're still having problems, your best is to create your own [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem.

*Edit*

Screenshot on how it looks under OS X with JDK1.7

[image: OS X screenshot]

Comment: This code shows me a JFileChooser where all files are greyed-out and not selectable, but still visible (OS X, JDK 1.7) +1 for the SSCCE, makes it very simple to test

Comment: @Robin: thanks for the heads up. On Windows 7, I don't see the files at all, just the directories. I wonder if this could be L&F dependent.

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft Full of Eels & Robin.

Yes, I can still see the files on my mac, using your example.  +1 on the SSCCE example and I'll definitely do that too in my future SO questions.

(I was hoping I could post an image here but turns out I need 10 reputation point or more before I could do that on SO.  Oops.)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added a screenshot to your post so others could clearly see that the `JFileChooser` behaves differently under OS X

Comment: @Alex: I've up-voted your original post as it was amazingly informative, well organized and with good code formatting for a first post. You should have your 10 rep points soon.

Comment: @trashgod - ah.  so it's a mac dealio with this.  Thanks!  (copying your comment here for future reference)

from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883447/jfilechooser-select-directory-but-show-files/2883595#2883595
"@mmyers: Empirically, it's platform-dependent, with files appearing gray in all supported L&Fs on Mac OS X. – trashgod May 21 '10 at 17:02"

Comment: @AlexKu: I think so; Robin's screenshot is illustrative.

Comment: Is there any workaround for Mac? I really don't want greyed-out files, just the selectable ones.

Comment: I've just run into this with an up to date Mac and am seeing the same problem. Files are visible and force me to do extra scrolling to get where I want. The problem showed up in my code and I've reproduced it just now with the Hovercraft SSCCE. I don't know of a solution.