# JavaFX - display files in the DirectoryChooser

Tags: javafx, filechooser

Is it possible to make the DirectoryChooser display files, not only directories? 
The same problem as described here [JFileChooser select directory but show files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883447/jfilechooser-select-directory-but-show-files) but in JavaFX.

Comment: I dont think that this is posible because javafx uses the System DirectoryChooser.

If you realy need that, take the JFileChooser or write your own...